# Store list of ids in a table cell - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to store list of ids (strings) in a SQL server table cell. These list of ids I'm getting while querying on another SQL server table.
These list of ids will be deserialized later into C# `List <string>` object.

I noticed that SQL server has some [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) table-value function which can create JSON (in my case a JSON array) but I don't know how to use that for my purpose.

**Update:** OPENJSON is supported from SQL server 2016 but our is SQL server 2012. So OPENJSON is out of the question now.

Any other approach is also fine as long as it storing the list in single cell and can be deserialized later directly to C# `List <string>` object.

---

*Note: I don't want to use a separate table for storing ids. This is just for migrating data.*

Answer (score 3):

You want to store a list of IDs in one single column. From your question I take, that you are aware of the fact, that everybody, how knows a bit about RDBMSs will give you the advise to store this in a `1:n`-related side table.

But you do not want this...

You have several choices:

- Store the IDs as CSV string (`3,4,17`) and use some sort of string split later
- Store the IDs as XML in an XML typed column (support goes down to SQL Server 2005) like `<IDs><ID>3</ID><ID>4</ID><ID>17</ID></IDs>`
- Store the JSON you have just as the string it is into a NVARCHAR(MAX) column

(AFAIK there are no plans to introdcue a *real* JSON type like there is `XML`. JSON will be a string on storage and in representation...)

There is JSON support starting with SQL Server 2016. Are all your target system that modern?

### UPDATE Create XML out of a `List<string>`

There are many ways, this is one of them:

```
var ListOfIds = new List<string>();
ListOfIds.Add("SomeID_1");
ListOfIds.Add("SomeID_2");
ListOfIds.Add("SomeID_3");

var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
var ids=xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "IDs", null);
foreach (string s in ListOfIds) {
    var id = ids.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ID", null));
    id.InnerText = s;
}
xdoc.AppendChild(ids);
var result = xdoc.InnerXml;
```

The result of this is a string like this

```
<IDs><ID>SomeID_1</ID><ID>SomeID_2</ID><ID>SomeID_3</ID></IDs>
```

You can pass this over to SQL Server as `unicode string` (C#'s default) into `XML` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` on SQL Server side. There you can read it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<IDs><ID>SomeID_1</ID><ID>SomeID_2</ID><ID>SomeID_3</ID></IDs>';
SELECT id.value(N'(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ID
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/IDs/ID') AS One(id)
```

### UPDATE 2

This will create an XML in the same format as above out of table data.
If you still need help **please start a new question!!**

```
SELECT SomeID AS [*] FROM SomeWhere FOR XML PATH('ID'),ROOT('IDs'),TYPE
```

Comment: I just found out that our's 2012 :P. You're right.. probably should go with XML. Could you also provide the create table query and inserting query to xml column. I've never used xml type before.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, please avoid chameleon questions... StackOverflow is not only a site to get help, but also a huge archive of answered questions. Therefore the principle: One issue - one question. The initial question was about *How to store a list of IDs in one single cell*, which seems to be solved. If so, please upvote and accept my answer by clicking the check below the vote counter to close this question and mark it as solved. Than start a new question for the new problem providing some more details and sample data.

Comment: sorry you took it other way but my question is still the same (storing list in cell). i was stating that i never used the xml in sql server so kind of hoping from you to be little bit more detailed about it (probably with an example)

Comment: @Jerry, see my update, but: No! I did not *take it the other way*! Your quesiton has a title, and that is what people are looking and searching for... This question is not *How can I store a C# `List<string>` in one single table column*. However... Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for nice example but my requirement is to store list of ids which i get from another sql table using INSERT INTO query. I want to store these list of ids in a cell. Later i want to deserialize these ids to list<string>. I mentioned the same in the question.

Comment: @Jerry, this is a perfect example of a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)! See my UPDATE 2 and please stop this, thx.

Comment: @JerryGoyal If I get this correctly, your question (at this state) is not even related to C#, this is really misleading...  Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: even i was not sure whether to put C# tag or not but then i'm using C# object for deserialization.so i put that. if it seems misleading i'll remove

Comment: And you are absolutely sure, that the tag `json` is not misleading? This quesiton fullfills all criteria of a chameleon now... What you should do: Think about *Is the initial question (as stated in your question) solved?* If yes: Vote on contributions, accept the best answer and start a new quesiton for further issues. Otherwise try to find your way with the given fragments. Do you get through? If not, the same as above. If yes, the same as above minus the new question :-D

Comment: hmm.. even the json tag is not valid now.. I see your point. it' better to ask the new question then.

Answer (score 1):

You can store ids as XML using "For XML" by retrieving data, in your case probably something like:

```
SELECT Id
FROM TableName
FOR XML AUTO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-auto-mode-with-for-xml

You can retrieve your XML Data using nodes() function like this:

```
SELECT r.value('@id','int')
FROM TargetTable
CROSS APPLY IdsColumn.nodes('/Root/Id') AS x(r)
```

It should work with SQL Server 2008 +

Comment: please provide specific details/code not links, what if those links get expired in future then your answer won't be valid anymore.

Comment: Your welcome. Hope it helps. But I hope also microsoft docs won't expire in the nearest future ;).